# How to handle large number of obstacles in a game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make an arcanoid game using python. The game is almost complete but i cannot find a way to identify which obstacle the ball is touching and to delete that single obstacle while bouncing back depending on the side of the obstacle it hit. I used tkinter to create a window in which i created a canvas. In the canvas i created a rectangle which is the player and a ball which bounces back from borders and the player. I need to create some obstacles and when the ball hits them it deletes them and bounces back. I tried creating a class obstacles to create them and it worked. After i tried to find a way to identify if the ball is touching an obstacle and which one from the total 84 is. The only idea i had was using the obstacles coordinates since it is a rectangle in a canvas and comparing them with the coordinates of the ball. When the ball would touch the obstacle it would delete it and bounce back. This only worked when i had one obstacle instead of 84. Here is the code i have until now:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import time

    WIDTH = 700
    HEIGHT = 550
    PLAYERCOLOR = "grey"

    class Ball: 
        def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, xvel, yvel, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.image = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = color)
            self.xvel = xvel
            self.yvel = yvel

        def move(self, coordinates1):
            global coordinates
            coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)
            self.canvas.move(self.image, self.xvel, self.yvel)
            if (coordinates[2] >= (self.canvas.winfo_width())):
                self.xvel = -2
            if (coordinates[0] < 0):
                self.xvel = 2
            if (coordinates[1] < 0):
                self.yvel = 3
            if (coordinates1[0] <= coordinates[2] <= coordinates1[2]) and (coordinates[3] == 450):
                self.yvel = -3
        
            

        
    class Obstacles:
        def  __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.image = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = color, tags = "obstacle")    
    
    def quit():
        window.destroy()

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Arcanoid")
    window.resizable(False, False)

    canvas = Canvas(window, bg = "black", height=HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
    x = 300
    id = canvas.create_rectangle(x, 450, x + 100, 460, fill = PLAYERCOLOR)
    ball = Ball(canvas, 345, 440, 355, 450, 2, -3, "white")


    window.update()
    window_width = window.winfo_width()
    window_height = window.winfo_height()
    screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

    x = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
    y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

    window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

    window.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: quit())
    x1 = -50
    x2 = 0
    colors = ["yellow", "red", "green", "blue", "purple", "light blue", "orange"]
    #creating the obstacles
    for i in range(14):
        x1 = x1 + 50
        x2 = x2 + 50
        y1 = 30
        y2 = 55
        if i <2:
            color = 1
        elif i <4:
            color = 6
        elif i <6:
            color = 0
        elif i <8:
            color = 2
        elif i <10:
            color = 5
        elif i <12:
            color = 3
        elif i <14:
            color = 4
        for j in range(6):
            y1 = y1 + 25
            y2 = y2 + 25
            obstacle = Obstacles(canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, colors[color])
            coords = [x1, y1, x2, y2] #storing the coordinates of the last obstacle only 
    boolean = True
    while True:
        coordinates1 = canvas.coords(id)
        ball.move(coordinates1)
        if (coordinates1[0] <= 0):
            window.unbind("<a>")
        elif (coordinates1[2] >= 700):
            window.unbind("<d>")
        else:
            window.bind("<a>", lambda event: canvas.move(id, -10, 0))
            window.bind("<d>", lambda event: canvas.move(id, 10, 0))
        #seeing from which side the ball hit the obstacle so it bounces back accordingly and delete it
        if (coords[0] <= coordinates[0] <= coords[2]) and (coordinates[1] == coords[3] + 1) and (boolean ==     True):
            ball.yvel = 3
            canvas.delete("obstacle") #uppon deleting the obstacle instead of deleting only the obstacle it hits it deletes all the obstacles
            boolean = False
        if (coords[0] <= coordinates[0] <= coords[2]) and (coordinates[3] == coords[1]) and (boolean == True):
            ball.yvel = -3
            canvas.delete("obstacle")
            boolean = False
        if (coords[1] <= coordinates[1] <= coords[3]) and (coordinates[0] == coords[2] + 1) and (boolean == True):
            ball.xvel = 2
            canvas.delete("obstacle")
            boolean = False
        if (coords[1] <= coordinates[1] <= coords[3]) and (coordinates[2] == coords[0] + 7) and (boolean == True):
            ball.xvel = -2
            canvas.delete("obstacle")
            boolean = False
        
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if  coordinates[3] > 460:
            canvas.delete("all")
            canvas.create_text(350, 250, fill = "red", text = "Game Over", font = ("Arial", 50))
            break
   window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.  Specifically, is your question how to restructure my code so it handles multiple obstacles, or is it something else?  Both are out of scope as written.

Comment: "Collision Detection" is a huge part of game development.  You should do a little research on some of the common techniques.  There should be a bunch of material freely available.  In general, you need to test the object (ball in your case) against *each* of the possible collision objects in every frame.  I don't see where you are doing that.  Take a look at `pygame` which would probably be easier to develop in than `tkinter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a function that returns the coordinates of the obstacle under the ball, or `None` if the ball isn't over an obstacle. You can then call that function inside your game loop each time the ball moves. If it returns something other than `None` you can delete the obstacle and change the trajectory of the ball.

The canvas has a method which will return all objects that overlap a set of coordinates, so you can call this method with the coordinates of the ball. Then you just need to loop over the results to return the first obstacle that it finds.

The function might look something like this (though, there are cleaner ways to implement this):

```
def find_obstacle():
    coordinates = ball.canvas.coords(ball.image)

    for iid in canvas.find_overlapping(*coordinates):
        tags = canvas.gettags(iid)
        if "obstacle" in tags:
            return iid
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I will try it but i am already trying to rewrite the game in pygame cause it is much easier to detect collitions. The problem i have now is that i can't give the ball a starting speed without it changing the movement later. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 550
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Arcanoid")

FPS = 60
XVEL = 2
YVEL = -3

Ball = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("ball2.png"))
Ball2 = pygame.transform.scale(Ball, (40, 40))



white = (255, 255, 255)

def draw_window(ball, player): #drawing the ball and the player which are both rectangles
    win.fill(white)
    win.blit(Ball2, (ball.x, ball.y))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), player)
    pygame.display.update()

def move(ball, player, XVEL, YVEL): 
        print(XVEL, YVEL) #when i print them here the always are 2 and - 3
        ball.x += XVEL #here i set a starting speed of xvel and yvel as constants outside the function but every time i call it the speeds change to the starting speeds
        ball.y += YVEL
        if (ball.x + XVEL) < 0:
            XVEL = 2
        if (ball.x + 40 + XVEL > WIDTH):
            XVEL = -2
            print(XVEL) #when printed here xvel is -2
        if (ball.y + YVEL < 0):
            YVEL = 3
        if (player.x < ball.x < player.x + 100) and (ball.y == 445): # i am gonna change that to check it with the detect collition function 
            YVEL = -3


def main(): #game's main loop
    player = pygame.Rect(300, 445, 100, 10)
    ball = pygame.Rect(330, 413, 40, 40)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            player.x -= 5
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            player.x += 5
        draw_window(ball, player)
        move(ball, player, XVEL , YVEL)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Noted: Your OP's code will work without  using `pgame`. I have a similar to your use of class instantiation.